# Android - Set backgroundresource to ImageView from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-imageview

I am trying to set a BackgroundResource to a ImageView from a sharedpreferences..

My Code is,

On Click Event of Button from Activity 1

```
    SharedPreferences settings;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

            settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt(GameScreen_SliderPuzzle1.key_image_id, R.drawable.image_3);

            editor.commit();
```

In Activity 2

```
SharedPreferences image_display;
    String image_id;

    image_display = context.getSharedPreferences(GameScreen_SliderPuzzle1.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    image_id = image_display.getString("key_image_id", "");     
    imageview.setBackgroundResource(image_id);
```

my problem is sharedpreferences value is in string and `setBackgroundResource` value is Int
I tried to convert string o int. but application crashes. `TypeCast Error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
image_id = image_display.getInt("key_image_id", 0);
```

as you need int not String.