# how to set value in setBackgroundResource

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to change a picture from another activity and display it as a picture or button, but it makes me a problem when I want to run the program, I'd love to help

```
imageView10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
        String s;

        SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences2 = enter.this.getSharedPreferences("two", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        s = mySharedPreferences2.getString("USERNAME2", "");

        s = "R.drawable.add1";
        imageView10.setBackgroundResource(s);
```

the s value is red...

Comment: try looking for your answer in this [Cilck Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300022/android-set-backgroundresource-to-imageview-from-sharedpreferences)

Comment: its not my mean